# Can not call string depending of Id linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I want to call my `StudentName` depending of Id selected that I use in selectlist to use in a bootstrap alert after post action, but I can not get it.

ViewModel:

```
public class StudentsViewModel
{
 public String StudentName { get; set; }//ForeignKey
    public int StudentId { get; set; }//ForeignKey
    public int SelectedStudent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Student{ get; set; }
}
}
```

Get Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Create(Students model)
    {
        var student= db.StudentsList.Select(x => x.StudentName).ToList();

        var vm = new StudentsViewModel
        {
            Student= new SelectList(db.StudentList, "StudentId", "StudentName"),
          StudentName = student.ToString()
        };
```

POST CONTROLLER:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(StudentsViewModel model)
    {

        var student =
          db.StudentsList.Where(x => x.StudentId == model.SelectedStudent)
              .Select(x => x.StudentName)
             .FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               var student=
         db.StudentsList.Where(x => x.StudentId == model.SelectedStudent)
             .Select(x => x.StudentName)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var studs= new Students
        {
            StudentId = model.SelectedStudent,
            StudentName = student
        };
        db.StudentsList.Add(studs);
        db.SaveChanges();  
                Success(string.Format("Register of" + student + "has been created"),true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Students");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Danger(string.Format("Cannot create your register"), true);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Index Students View(Where I want to display my bootstrap alert)

```
 @model IEnumerable<xxx.Models.Student>

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

 <h2>Index</h2>

 <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
  </p>
  <table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.StudentName)
    </th>


 @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.StudentName)
    </td>



    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StudentId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StudentId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.StudentId })
    </td>
</tr>
 }

 </table>
```

Create View:

```
  @model xxx.Models.ViewModels.StudentViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

 <h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Students</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStudent, Model.Student, "-Select an option-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedStudent)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

So my consult is

```
var student= db.StudentsList.Where(x => x.StudentId == model.SelectedStudent).Select(x => x.StudentName).FirstOrDefault();
```

But in my call `StudentName = student` I put a breakpoint and always come null.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: could you please show your view(html) code?

Comment: @RamSingh Yes there is

Comment: put a hidden field and on change of drop down fill value to that hidden field and set model property for same field. i think in this way you can do it

Comment: As I understand in my view I use a @html.hiddenfor(x => x.Studentname) but how can I fill this value of my Index when Im do post action (create view)?

Comment: @RamSingh sorry I dont tag you

Comment: `var student= db.StudentsList.Select(x => x.StudentName).ToList();` return a collection so `StudentName = student.ToString()` return `System.Collections.Generic.List[Student]` so using a hidden input for that property is pointless and would never bind to anything. It impossible to understand what your trying to do here

Comment: And is you last line of code is returning `null`, then show the view (for the `Create()` method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke there is my create view

Comment: What I trying to do is call Selected StudentName of the dropdown of my create and show in my bootstrap alert

Comment: Based on your view, you view model should contain only 2 properties - `int SelectedStudent` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Student` (although I strongly recommend you follow normal naming conventions and use `StudentList` or `Students`). But what is the point of your code - all your doing is selecting an existing student from your `StudentsList` table and then saving exactly the same record back to the table.

Comment: And what do you mean _I want to display my bootstrap alert_? What alert?

Comment: I show only relevant code, another fields are not relevant for question

Comment: Well if you have any form controls for those other 2 properties it certainly is relevant since it would cause it to fail!

Comment: I made a class that calling my custom alerts

Comment: What class? And how does it pass a value to the view? And how are you displaying it in the view. Sorry, but nothing here makes sense.

Comment: Values I post are unique of process, I don't have anything corresponding with Student than these properties